# Is there a trick to using d3 charts in jsf?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces, d3.js, liferay-6

I am using Prime Faces in Liferay, What is the trick to getting the D3 examples to show up in jsf land specifically Prime Faces on Liferay. The example I am trying to make work in JSF is this one: 
[How would d3.js difference chart example work with json data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446437/how-would-d3-js-difference-chart-example-work-with-json-data)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. The trick is to reference a div element instead of body. All of the examples I have seen use "body".In a portal container you don't want to use body as that will put you outside of your port let. A div is required and must be referenced as in the javascript. I have included the new code below

```
    <%@ page import="javax.portlet.WindowState" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://alloy.liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>


    <portlet:defineObjects />

    <form action="<portlet:actionURL />" method="post" name="<portlet:namespace />fm">
    <div id="svgContainer" ></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.area()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d["student"]); });

    var area = d3.svg.area()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d["student"]); });

    var svg = d3.select("#svgContainer").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    var count =0;

    d3.json("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/data/data.json", function(error, data) {
      if(error) return console.warn(error);
          data.data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d["student"]= +d["student"];
            d["average"] = +d["average"];
            count++;

          });

      x.domain(d3.extent(data.data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

      y.domain([
        d3.min(data.data, function(d) { return Math.min(d["student"], d["average"]); }),
        d3.max(data.data, function(d) { return Math.max(d["student"], d["average"]); })
      ]);

      svg.datum(data.data);

      svg.append("clipPath")
          .attr("id", "clip-below")
        .append("path")
          .attr("d", area.y0(height));

      svg.append("clipPath")
          .attr("id", "clip-above")
        .append("path")
          .attr("d", area.y0(0));

      svg.append("path")
          .attr("class", "area above")
          .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-above)")
          .attr("d", area.y0(function(d) { return y(d["average"]); }));

      svg.append("path")
          .attr("class", "area below")
          .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-below)")
          .attr("d", area);

      svg.append("path")
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", line);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Grades");
    });



    </script>
    </form>
```