# stacked area graph by json file in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, stacked-area-chart

Does any one know any example in which the D3.js graphs (stacked area graphs) built by a json file. All I have found is based on tsv or csv.

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried it with flair.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found quite a bit:

- One that draws shapes (http://www.dashingd3js.com/using-json-to-simplify-code)
- And the other that draws a graph (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045)
- A helpful article that explains data transition with (out) AJAX (http://empire5.com/development/d3-js-dynamic-bar-graphing-with-transitions-and-json/)
- Also, check out this question, [How would d3.js difference chart example work with json data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446437/how-would-d3-js-difference-chart-example-work-with-json-data)

I hope this helps!