# How to add negative values to JavaFx Area Chart?

Tags: charts, javafx, stacked-area-chart

I'd like to draw a difference (area) chart, something like this:
[How would d3.js difference chart example work with json data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446437/how-would-d3-js-difference-chart-example-work-with-json-data)
where my chart is centered around horizontal (y=0) axis.

JavaFx's Area chart seems to know how to fill only the area below the line!?

[Example "Adding negative value" (Fig 33-7)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/area-chart.htm#CIHICDIB) seems to be what I'm looking for (March series) **BUT it does not work/render as shown!**

Instead of:

[image]

it renders:

[image]

Thanks,

Igor

Comment: I ran sample 33-7 and also got the same result as you (i.e. the chart rendered by the program did not match the picture in the documentation).  My test system was Java 8u40 on OS X 10.9.  I advise that you [log a bug report](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) against the JavaFX runtime project.

Comment: How am I supposed to do that? I don't have an account, cannot log in, and it says that I'm supposed to contact "my JIra admin" which is nowhere to be found?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that you cannot create an account in the JavaFX bug tracker.   Until very recently, you could self-register an account in the JavaFX bug tracker, but it looks like that feature was disabled.  According to the JavaFX mailing list, [JavaFX will be switching to using the openjdk based bug tracker](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2015-April/017083.html), and JavaFX bugs can now be reported at: http://bugreport.java.com (click the "Start a new Report" button at the bottom of the page).

Comment: Thank jewelsea, I've reported the bug. I cannot post the link for the time being, since it is under review:

"We are evaluating this report and have stored this with an Review ID: JI-9021201. In the event this report is determined as a defect or enhancement request, it will be referenced with a new Bug ID and will be listed on Bugs.java.com. "

Comment: Here it is:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8081715